# AVFoundation custom video player doesn't display the video?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm building a custom video player. To create it, I use play button and view. The video I want to see in the player, I get from the iPhone's Photos. The problem with the player is that I have a working URL of the video, but the view just doesn't display that, actually here is the code of it:`

```
@IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: Any) {
    print("play video")

    let videoURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: uurl.url!)!
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)
    playerLayerr = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayerr.frame = vlogView.bounds
    self.vlogView!.layer.addSublayer(playerLayerr)
    player.play()

}
```

The interesting fact is that player finds the video because I can hear the video, but it's not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the bellow code ,it is working for me.

```
@IBOutlet weak var vlogView: UIView!

         var avPlayer = AVPlayer()
         var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

       @IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: Any) {
    let videoURL =  URL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
        avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
        self.avPlayerLayer.frame = self.vlogView.frame
        avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        vlogView.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)
        vlogView.layoutIfNeeded()
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL!)
        avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
        avPlayer.play()
        }
```

Comment: it works, but not at the full size of this view. I would be very happy to mark your answer as correct, it is actually correct, but this is the only one problem

Comment: there is also one more problem and it's that if I tap the play button again, it won't play, it plays a video only for 1 first time and no more, maybe you know how to deal with that? Tried on 2 different iPhones - the same.

Comment: I took one sample video URL is replaying every time for each button 'action.avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)' will replace new video with existed video.

Comment: I updated my answer for playing video full screen .You have to specify 'videoGravity' for playing video in viewbounds